John Preskill Problem 3.5c
I am trying to solve this problem from John Preskill's lecture notes just for my understanding:

Consider a single-qubit channel with a unitary representation
$$\newcommand\ket[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}\begin{align}\ket{0}_A\ket{0}_E\to\sqrt{1-p}\ket{0}_A\ket{0}_E+\sqrt{p}\ket{0}_A\ket{\gamma_0}_E\\
\ket{1}_A\ket{0}_E\to\sqrt{1-p}\ket{1}_A\ket{0}_E+\sqrt{p}\ket{1}_A\ket{\gamma_1}_E\end{align}$$
where $\ket{\gamma_0}_E$ and $\ket{\gamma_1}_E$ are normalized states, both orthogonal to $\ket{0}_E$, that satisfy
$$\phantom{a}_E\left\langle\gamma_0\middle|\gamma_1\right\rangle_E=1-\varepsilon,\quad0<\varepsilon<1.$$
Show that this is again the phase-damping channel, and find its operator-sum representation with two Kraus operators.

This is what I have so far: In order to get to an operator-sum representation we have to use an ON-basis. This can be done by replacing $|\gamma_1\rangle$ with (refer Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization):
$|\gamma_2\rangle = |\gamma_1\rangle - \langle \gamma_0 | \gamma_1 \rangle |\gamma_0\rangle$
Now $\{ |0\rangle, | \gamma_0 \rangle, | \gamma_2 \rangle \}$ can be seen to form an ON-basis for the environment. Taking the partial trace and applying the usual steps, this gives me following operators:
$M_0 = \sqrt{1-p}I, M_1 = \sqrt{p} \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & k(1-\epsilon) \end{array} \right), M_2 = \sqrt{p} \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & k \end{array} \right)$
where $k(\epsilon)$ is just a normalization constant (depends on $\epsilon$) to ensure $| \gamma_2 \rangle $ has length 1. The part where I am struggling is to find an operator-sum representation using only 2 operators. Either my $M_0, M_1, M_2$ are wrong or maybe there is a mistake in the question. I also noticed that $M_0 M_0^\dagger + M_1 M_1^\dagger + M_2 M_2^\dagger \neq I$. Can anyone help me with this?

a standard way to find a minimal Kraus decomposition is to pass through the Choi matrix. Compute the Choi matrix, diagonalise it, and its eigenvectors will correspond to the Kraus operators
